# Ubuntu 14.04 won't load to empty Hard drive (2)

Tags: boot, system-installation

I asked this question on 12/31/14 and got response from Virusboy and gyropyge. I followed their advise, deleting all partitions.The drive was then unallocated. I then attempted to  install Ubuntu 14.04-iso from a dvd. I set all 3 boot options in the BIOS to boot from the CDROM. Upon restarting, after the BIOS processed , I get "missing operating system" which repeats until I shut down. I then changed the drive from "unallocated" to one primary partition. Same result, "missing operating system". What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning me.  I was wondering why this looked familiar.  Depending upon the brand and model of your laptop, it may be necessary to press another key such as ESC or F8 to persuade your PC to boot from the DVD drive.

Edit:  Explained in my comments below, it appears the button you need to press to bring up the boot menu is F12

Comment: I am a nube to Ask Ubuntu, so mistakenly posted a follow-up comment in the answer box. You obviously saw that.Since neither of the first answers worked, I reread Virusboy's suggestion to "wipe the drive...." and used DBAN, then Parted Magic to rebuild an ext2 partition. Ubuntu 14.04 still would not load so I tried WinXP. It loaded, so now I have XP on a 30 GB part and an ext2 remainder of the drive. I still can't load 14.04. can you help me?

Comment: I failed to respond to your comments about my computer. It is home built with a Gigabyte EP45T-USB3P MB, Intel Xeon E3110@3.00 GHz CPU. Award modular BIOS V6.00PG 1984-2005. It has 2 HD

Comment: I failed to respond to your comments about my computer. It is home built with a Gigabyte GA8IPE1000-G MB,Pentium4,3GHz/512/800-SLWK CPU. Award modular BIOS V6.00PG 1984-2005. It has 2 HD's, 40 GB and the 160GB drive I am currently trying to modify.

Comment: Please ignore the comment about the computer with the Gigabyte EP45T-USB3P

Comment: Gigabyte does not list very detailed information about that motherboard online so it is convenient I have the owner's manual to a similar motherboard here.  If yours is similar to mine, pressing F12 at boot time should bring up the boot menu and permit you to boot to your DVD drive.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem. Jan 5 i rec'vd the 4th edition of Sobell's ubuntu manual in the mail. In the back is a 14.04 DVD. I tried it and got a message the my mobo and CPU does not support Trusty Tahr. I am now in process of upgrading this machine,(my wife's). A new mobo, CPU and mem is on the way. I should have it up and running in a week. I thank you for your patience and help. PS; I have not found any minimum hardware standards for the Trusty Tahr distro on the net.